# Pass dynamic checkbox values to next JSP page

Tags: mysql, jsp, checkbox

I have aproblem. Here I am showing some bills from Invoice table in mysql. And for single bill I am keeping a checkbox. I want to pass selected checkbox values to next jsp page. Please help me to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
<%
    String company_name=request.getParameter("c_name");  
        try
        {
            Integer count=0;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t_fleet","root","aadi");  
        Statement st = con.createStatement();  
        String sql="select invoice_no, invoice_date, gross_amount from tbl_invoice where client='"+company_name+"'";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        %>
        <center>
            <table id="show_table">
            <tr>
                <td>PNR No</td>
                <th>Date</td>
                <th>Amount</td>
                <th>Select</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                while(rs.next())
                {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getInt(3)%></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="ck"/></td>
            </tr>

            %>
            </table>
        </center>
        <%
                    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

%>

Comment: check if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/N6Ajq/

Comment: No man its not that much helpful to me because i am adding checkboxes at runtime. so please suggest me some more. Thanks for your time.

Comment: one problem u have is ur name is same for all i.e its `ck`.incase you send your data to the action wid same name it will give just one value since your name of the checkbox is same for all checkboxes

Comment: Santino, can i use request.getParameterValues() method? I think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution. On action page where I am going to receive values I will store all checkbox names in a array of string.

```
String selected_Checkboxes=request.getParameterValues("ck");
```

I will just change "td" tag of checkbox. I will put value of PNR NO which is coming from database and will put in checkbox.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="<%=rs.getInt(1)%>" name="ck"/></td>
```

I will use indexes of "selected_Checkboxes" to do further coding.

--Thanks Santino 'Sonny' Coleone